# Error while trying to install Intel Software (in order to update graphics)

Tags: package-management, security, ppa, update-manager, repository

I have been trying to update my graphic card for a while now and I found in the Intel website a .deb package that helps you to keep your graphics up to date. However, while running it, I keep getting the same error that I see in the terminal:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu xenial
Release' does not have a Release file. N: Data from such a repository
can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
configuration details. 
W: GPG error:
https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial InRelease: The
following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
not available: NO_PUBKEY 56A3DEF863961D39 
W: The repository
'https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial InRelease' is
not signed. N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and
is therefore potentially dangerous to use. N: See apt-secure(8)
manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. W:
http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian/dists/lsb3.2/Release.gpg:
Signature by key F8897B6F00075648E248B7EC24CBF5474CFD1E2F uses weak
digest algorithm (SHA1) 
E: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found E: Some index files failed to download. They have been
ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Is there any way to fix this? Do I need to delete those files or try to download them again?

Comment: My recommendation is not to install them. They're problematic. They're somewhat difficult to roll back. And, they're released MONTHS after new Ubuntu releases hit the streets. Cheers, Al

Comment: Either way I need to do something about it because this error is stopping the installation of Intel Graphics so that's why I was asking in the first place.

Comment: Please see my answer, below. Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

**Problem #1:** You have an incorrect repository defined. Change

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu xenial main

to

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu trusty main

or better yet, use their direct location at:

deb https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial main
```

**Problem #2:** You don't have a GPG key installed. In terminal, enter

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-4 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add - (including the ending hyphen)
```

**For more info**, head to their web site at https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2.

Cheers, Al

Comment: I've tried both things and none of them apparently worked. I already downloaded the .deb package from Intel and it keeps failing due to these errors. I've tried to retrieve the keys and that command doesn't work either.

Comment: You have to give me more details. Where/how did you edit the first change? What error message did you receive on the wget command? Did you copy/paste, or manually type them in? Cheers, Al

Comment: Check my update for deb location. Cheers, Al